# Run VTK 7.0 with OpenGL 2.1

Tags: c++, opengl, vtk

I use VKT only for easy Volume rendering. Now I am upgrading VTK from 5.10 to 7.0 and it does not work on many computers. The problem is the standard Intel(R) HD Graphics Card with OpenGL 2.1. I have read that the new VTK Rendering backend needs an OpenGL version 3.2. Now is there any workaround to get that running? Must I take an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not a problem for you to distribute your software together with VTK, you can easily compile your own VTK from the sources. You just need to switch the VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND CMake variable to "OpenGL" (from 7.0 onwards, the default is "OpenGL2"), this way you will have the legacy code that will run with openGL 2.1. If you are not compiling VTK yourself, I am afraid there is no official package compiled with the old backend, or at least not that I know of.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to recompile VTK from source.